# Parameterized pipeline with choice has trailing comma

Tags: jenkins

I have a jenkins pipeline which uses the defualt choice parameter.

```
    parameters {
        choice(choices:  ['optA', 'optB'], description: 'Some options', name: 'CHOSEN')
    }
```

Whenever it run the chosen options will always have a comma appended to it. Resulting in the step it's used in taking it as part of the argument.

```
someprogram.sh optA,
```

This breaks everything. How do I disable the comma? Also why is this default behavior?

I tried removing it with a combination of shell substition and jenkins groovy string manipulation.
I searched for the option 'omit field value' which 'fixes' this for a choices plugin (I am not using the reactive choices plugin but this is the only response I could find) When I try to find the 'omit field value' box in pipeline settings in parameters it doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing it like below.

```
sh "someprogram.sh ${params.CHOSEN}"
```